# Understanding tweet time creation from twitteR package (R)

Tags: r, twitter

What accounts for the time difference between the twitteR tweet 'created' column and the actual tweet time? If I look at hadleywickham's tweet, for example, it is tweeted at 10:39 am as seen on twitter. The tweet creation time, however, from userTimeline("hadleywickham, 15) is 17:39 (as shown below from the images). Is the time randomized or is there a way to account for this difference?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The time returned by the R package is UTC. The time shown in the web interface is what Twitter thinks is the local time for the user. Hadley is based in Houston TX.

Comment: Some code for dealing with this?  Upvote if you can do it!

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! 10:39 AM CDT to UTC will be 3:39 PM, which converted to military would be 15:39 so it still seems to lag behind 17:39. Any suggestions on what could account for this discrepancy?

Comment: Daylight saving could add/remove another hour. But we don't know where a user was when they sent the tweet, or what local time was according to their computer. If you knew their local time, you could convert using _e.g._ `lubridate::as_datetime(tab$created, tz = "US/Central")`.